# CMakeLists.txt and two .cmake files

Tags: c++, cmake

I have two *.cmake files, lets say nacl.cmake and pnacl.cmake in my ./CMake/ folder. How do I cmake using the specific one using my CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 5):

Make an [option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aoption) to let user switch between them:

```
option(USE_PNACL "Use PNaCl instead fo NaCl" TRUE)

if(USE_PNACL)
  include(CMake/PNacl.cmake)
else()
  include(CMake/Nacl.cmake)
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

They sound like two alternative [toolchains](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html). You can chose between different toolchains during configuration with the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` option:

```sh
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<project-folder>/CMake/PNacl.cmake <project-folder>
```

If you don't specify a toolchain file, the build system will target the build machine.